# AWS lambda error while connecting to Dynamodb

Tags: java, lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis

I am getting out of memory error when connecting to dynamodb for kinesis consumer.

```
public void recordHandler(KinesisEvent event) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Entering record Handler");
        try {
            AmazonDynamoDB client = new AmazonDynamoDBClient();
            client.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.US_WEST_2));
            DynamoDB dynamoDB = new DynamoDB(client);
            Table table = dynamoDB.getTable("feeds");
            System.out.println("Event records size" + event.getRecords().size());
        for(KinesisEventRecord rec : event.getRecords()) {

//put item to table. 
}
```

Can anyone point what i might be doing wrong. Also i have the dynamo table in the same region as lambda and kinesis stream.

Error:

```
Metaspace: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Metaspace
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.document.DynamoDB.getTable(DynamoDB.java:89)
```

Comment: First, does increasing the memory allocation for the lambda helps? what's the minimum amount of memory for which the lambda does work?

Comment: How much memory have you allocated to your lambda function?

Comment: Increasing the memory from 128 to 512 fixed the issue. Thanks for replying @johni